# cv-qualifiers and implicit type conversion

Tags: c++

In the code,

```
const int x = 3;
int y = 0;
y += x;
```

Is there any need to remove the const from x before doing the addition or is this maybe done implicitly in the addition operator definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, the `+=` operator is an *assignment* operator (compound assignment). Its behavior though is equivalent to `y = y + x` combination (except `y` is evaluated only once).

Secondly, when used as an operand of addition operator (including the RHS of `+=` as in your example) `x` participates in the expression as an *rvalue*, i.e. it is implicitly subjected to so called *lvalue-to-rvalue conversion*. This conversion immediately discards `const`, since rvalues of non-class types (`int` in your case) cannot be cv-qualified.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Done implicitly, since you're not going to change `x`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remove `const` if `x` is used only as in given snippet.

The `const` modifier marks one variable as holding read-only data. If the compiler sees that you are modifying it, it will get angry and report an error. For all other uses, `const` is dropped.

In your case, you aren't modifying `x` so there's no need for `const` removal.

Comment: The runtime may get angry if you were to try to modify `x` after removing `const`. :)